# Creating interface for abstract type in Fortran 90

Tags: generics, interface, fortran, abstract, fortran90

I am coding in Fortran90 and even if I know it should be avoided I need to use abstract types.
And now I wish to define a function that can take either the abstract type or a derived type in the argument. For this I wanted to create an interface of both functions but I get the following error :

> Ambiguous interfaces 'initialize_abstract' and
>   'initialize_logic' in generic interface
>   'initialize' at (1)

The code look like this :

```
type type1
contains
procedure, pass(transf) :: initialize_logic
procedure, pass(transf) :: initialize_abstract
end type

interface initialize
     module procedure initialize_logic
     module procedure initialize_abstract
end interface

function initialize_logic(element, element_logic)
   type(type1), pointer :: element
   type(type_logic), pointer :: element_logic
end function

function initialize_abstract(element, element_abstract)
    type(type1), pointer :: element
    class(type_abstract), pointer :: element_abstract
end function
```

With type_abstract is extended from type_logic.

I don't know how to get rid of this message error, and I really need to be able to call it with either an abstract type or the exteneded type (here: "logic_type"), for example :

```
class(type_abstract), pointer :: element_abstract
type(type_logic),     pointer :: element_logic
type(type1)                   :: e1, e2
call e1%initialize(element_abstract)
call e2%initialize(element_logic)
```

If I just have one initializer, taking in parameter the abstract class, I get the following error, when initializing with the extended type :

> Error: Actual argument to 'element_abstract' at (1) must have the same declared type

Any ideas ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Your `type1` definition appears not to be related.  Did you mean to write something else?

Comment: Is just the type that I am defining and that I wish to initialize with the functions initialize_... I changed the code a little bit so it is a bit more explicit. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Can you show the definitions of `type_abstract` and `type_logic`? It is not very clear to me what is what. I am especially confused if by abstract you mean an abstract class.

Comment: Oh, I think I got it although it is still not clear to me what you are doing. How is the compiler supposed to disambiguate `initialize_logic` and `initialize_abstract`? If `logic` extends `abstract` then calling `initialize(element,element_something)` can mean both `initialize_logic` and `initialize_abstract` since `element_something` is both `type(logic)` and `class(abstract)`. Something along these lines must be happening.

Comment: Yes, indeed this is the problem. But if I have only one initializer, let's say with the abstract class, I cannot call (directly) the initializer with an extend type (here : type_logic)

Comment: To be accurate, you're not coding in Fortran 90.  Type-bound procedures, such as your `initialize_abstract`, were introduced in the 2003 standard.  As were `abstract` types, though your code makes no use of them despite your frequent use of the word *abstract*.

Comment: This article -- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/b10932b4-0edd-4e61-89f2-6e478ccba9aa/entry/object_oriented_fortran_user_defined_constructors2?lang=en -- explains better than I have time for now (possibly better than I am capable of) how to create constructors for user defined types.  This -- https://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v3n1a3.htm -- is also good.

Comment: Remove fortran90 tag from the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** Completely reworked, added the abstract class approach.

There are two ways how to do it. One uses the `select type` construct to determine the dynamic type of `element` at run time to call the right initialization procedure.

The other approach uses an abstract class to declare a deferred procedure `initialize_t1` which will be implemented by each subclass differently. Note two things, first I called one of the derived types `abstract` to keep your naming convention however it is rather confusing and not a good practice. The truly abstract class is then called `veryAbstract` to give a hint of its purpose and still keep your naming convention. The other point to note is that the `initialize_from_...` procedures are bound to the `veryAbstract` subclasses not to the `type1` class. This may be confusing but it is the trick which allows to achieve what you are after.

Both ways were tested with ifort 14.

Approach 1 (select type):

```
module test2

type abstract 
        integer :: x
      contains
end type abstract

type, extends(abstract) :: logic 
        integer :: y
      contains
end type logic

type type1
        integer :: x
      contains
              procedure :: initialize => initialize_type1
              procedure :: initialize_abstract
              procedure :: initialize_logic
end type type1

      contains

subroutine initialize_abstract(this,element)
              class(type1),    intent(inout) :: this
              class(abstract), intent(in)    :: element
              this%x = element%x
end subroutine initialize_abstract 

subroutine initialize_logic(this,element)
              class(type1), intent(inout) :: this
              class(logic), intent(in)     :: element
              this%x = element%y
end subroutine initialize_logic 

subroutine initialize_type1(this,element)
        class(type1),    intent(inout) :: this
        class(abstract), intent(in)    :: element

        select type (element)
           type is (abstract)
                   call this%initialize_abstract(element)
           type is (logic)
                   call this%initialize_logic(element)
           class default
                   print*,"ERROR: Unknown type of the 'element' argument in 'initialize_type1'."
                   stop
        end select
end subroutine initialize_type1 
end module test2
```

Approach 2 (abstract class):

```
module test3
type type1
        integer :: x
      contains
              procedure :: initialize => initialize_type1
end type type1

type, abstract :: veryAbstract
        contains
                procedure(init_t1), deferred :: initialize_t1
end type veryAbstract

abstract interface
   subroutine init_t1(this,t1)
           import veryAbstract
           import type1
           class(veryAbstract), intent(in)    :: this
           class(type1),        intent(inout) :: t1
   end subroutine
end interface

type, extends(veryAbstract) :: abstract 
        integer :: x
      contains
              procedure :: initialize_t1 => initialize_type1_from_abstract
end type abstract

type, extends(abstract) :: logic 
        integer :: y
      contains
              procedure :: initialize_t1 => initialize_type1_from_logic
end type logic

      contains

subroutine initialize_type1(this,element)
        class(type1),    intent(inout) :: this
        class(abstract), intent(in)    :: element
        call element%initialize_t1(this)
end subroutine initialize_type1     

subroutine initialize_type1_from_abstract(this,t1)
              class(abstract), intent(in)    :: this
              class(type1),    intent(inout) :: t1
              t1%x = this%x
end subroutine initialize_type1_from_abstract 

subroutine initialize_type1_from_logic(this,t1)
              class(logic), intent(in)    :: this
              class(type1), intent(inout) :: t1
              t1%x = this%y
end subroutine initialize_type1_from_logic 

end module test3
```

Test programme:

```
PROGRAM test 
    use test2
    !use test3

    type(abstract) :: a1
    type(logic)    :: l1
    type(type1)    :: t1
    type(type1)    :: t2

    a1%x = 1
    l1%x = 2
    l1%y = 7
    call t1%initialize(a1)
    call t2%initialize(l1)

    print*,'t1%x: ',t1%x
    print*,'t2%x: ',t2%x
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem is that your type "abstract" should be declared as such, ie :
`type,abstract :: abstract 
        integer :: x
      contains
end type abstract`
In this case the first solution doesn't work, for the second one, I don't think it would work either, but I will give it a try

Comment: Because your abstract type is not abstract

Comment: @lasofivec OK, I got it. You do not understand how `abstract` classes work. You cannot instantiate an abstract class that is just not possible. Hence you cannot do what you want. The way to do it is either not to make `abstract` an abstract class (ie approach 1) or to use approach 2.

Comment: I am not trying to instantiate an abstract class, my problem is more complex than what I described (type1 is actually also an abstract type) and definitely more complex than your test case. I will try to write one so that it's more clear. But thanks for your answers in any case :)

Comment: @lasofivec Well, I asked you already on Friday to clarify what you were doing. Even now in the question `type1` is not abstract (it wasn't even clear that `abstract` was abstract). I answered the question that I could see and I believe I gave two valid ways of doing that. I am sad to hear it does not work for you but that is not surprising if you do something else than what you say. I wonder how anyone can answer such a question then.